# Search for usage of a class object with a given operator? [Eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse

For example, let's say I want to find all instances of using the == operator with any string object, so that I can replace it with .equals() instead.  How can I do such a search?  Otherwise I'd have to pick through all my code line-by-line... Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't have any special search capabilities for operators.  That doesn't mean that you can't do a file search for them though.

You're probably better off running [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/strings.html) to find issues like this for you.

Comment: PMD allows you to write your own rules very easily, using XPath or Java. Does FindBugs do that too?

Comment: "Does FindBugs do that too?"

Not *easily*. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

FindBugs may produce warning for this type of coding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do a File Search for '=="' and '== "' in all files.

CTRL-H -> File Search tab

```
Containing text: =="
File name patterns: *.java
```

And then do the same for the string == " (note there is a space between the == and the "

Comment: It does not work if you compare string variable like in if (oneString == anotherString)